# Xamarin forms get Phone language IOS does not work but work on Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using xamarin forms. I am trying to get the phone language (real phone). The code gives me english while my phone is in French. when try with android phone (real phone), it works and I have french.

Here is the code :

```
string phoneLanguage = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
```

Here is the output on IOS :

```
 en
```

Here is the output on android :

```
fr
```

Both phone (real phone) are in french but only IOS gives me `en`. I have tried with another Iphone but I still have `en`

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show us more of the relevant code and how you've set up the localization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS first looks up your user's most preferred language and sees if the language is supported by the program. You can check if your program localizations bundled (.lproj) has French files. Then you can also check whether the following key-value pairs are added in the Info.plist file of your application to set the supported languages, like this:

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>en</string>
    <string>fr</string>
    ...
</array>
```

You can detect the device's current locale using the following methods:

```
var userLoc = NSLocale.CurrentLocale.LocaleIdentifier;
```

For more details you can refer to:

[Localization in Xamarin.iOS | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/)

[How iOS Determines the Language For Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1828/_index.html)